# Instantiate new class object in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have a albums and images models. In my albums `show.html.erb` I have the following code:

```
<% @album.images.each do |image| %>

<p>
  <strong>name:</strong>
  <%= image.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>url:</strong>
  <%= image.image_url(:thumb) %>
</p>

<%=  AlbumsHelper::Image.new({url:image.image_url(:thumb),
                             attributes:{title:image.name,
                                         description: image.description}
                            }).render.html_safe
%>

<% end %>
```

The `AlbumsHelper::Image` class `render` method simply renders html template. The issue is that the `name` and the `url` of each image are different, but the rendered html template is the same for all images.

I guess I am not instantiating in the correct way new objects from my `AlbumsHelper::Image` class. Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
  class Image

    IMAGE_NOT_FOUND = 'http://fuge.it/images/phoca_thumb_l_no_image.gif'
    THUMBNAIL_TEMPLATE = [
                          '<div class="view">',
                            '<div class="view-back">',
                              '<span data-icon="A">##title##</span>',
                              '<span data-icon="B">##description##</span>',
                              '<a href="##url##">→</a>',
                            '</div>',
                            '<div class="slice s1" style="background-image: url(##url##);">',
                              '<span class="overlay"></span>',
                              '<div class="slice s2" style="background-image: url(##url##);">',
                                '<span class="overlay"></span>',
                                '<div class="slice s3" style="background-image: url(##url##);">',
                                  '<span class="overlay"></span>',
                                  '<div class="slice s4" style="background-image: url(##url##);">',
                                    '<span class="overlay"></span>',
                                    '<div class="slice s5" style="background-image: url(##url##);">',
                                      '<span class="overlay"></span>',
                                    '</div>',
                                  '</div>',
                                  '</div>',
                                '</div>',
                            '</div>',
                          '</div>',
                          ].join('')

    attr_accessor :url,         # image source url
                  :attributes   # data attributes

    def initialize(parameters = {})
      @url = parameters.fetch(:url, IMAGE_NOT_FOUND)
      @attributes = parameters.fetch(:attributes, {})

      @url = IMAGE_NOT_FOUND unless File.extname(@url) =~/^(.png|.gif|.jpg)$/ #@url =~/^#{URI::regexp}$/ and
      @attributes = Hash.new unless @attributes.is_a?(Hash)
    end

    def to_s
      "<img src=#{@url} #{@attributes.map{|key,value| "data-#{key}=#{value}" }.join(' ')}/>"
    end

    def render(parameters = {})

      has_thumbnail = parameters.fetch(:has_thumbnail, 0)
      thumbnail_template = parameters.fetch(:thumbnail_template, THUMBNAIL_TEMPLATE)

      if has_thumbnail
        @attributes.map { |key, value| thumbnail_template["##{key}##"] &&= value }
        thumbnail_template.gsub!('##url##', @url)
        thumbnail_template
      else
        self.to_s
      end
    end


  end
```

Comment: Can you include your helper class?

Comment: I might not be understanding the total reasoning behind this setup. Wouldn't this be easier as a partial? You could then just render the partial in the loop

Comment: I am planning to move this code in a ruby gem - creating gem is the goal.

Comment: (1) `THUMBNAIL_TEMPLATE` would be a good candidate for a heredoc. (2) You might want to use `%{title}` and such in `THUMBNAIL_TEMPLATE` and then use [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25) to fill things in `THUMBNAIL_TEMPLATE % { :title => '...', :description => '...', ... }`, that would (IMO) be cleaner than doing it by hand with `String#gsub`.

Comment: @muistooshort As I debug this it seems that the template placeholders are replaced for the first image and then the same template is used for the rest images. What do you mean saying `good candidate for a heredoc?`

Comment: I'd use a heredoc (or a single `%q{...}`) because that array of strings thing is brittle and hideous. Why are you using `gsub!` to modify your string in-place? You probably have hidden reference sharing and your `gsub!` is modifying things that you don't expect it to; either `gsub` or my `String#%` approach would avoid that problem.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, my lack of knowledge puts me here. Using a `!` with  the `gsub` method was the issue. Thanks for helping me clearing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thumbnail_template.gsub! changes your constant and replaces your placeholders with actual values. You can either add dup to copy the string

```
thumbnail_template = parameters.fetch(:thumbnail_template, THUMBNAIL_TEMPLATE).dup
```

or use gsub instead of gsub! and assign the returned value to a new variable.

You can also add `.freeze` to the constant to raise an error if the code tries to modify its value.

Also, why not render and .erb partial instead of manually manipulating string and reinventing the wheel?